# Postman API -how to pass environment variable to another request jason body

Tags: postman

1. I have create global variable. Set it as Test as env variaable corresponding quote id were stored in the CreateGLVar

`pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);});
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("CreateGLVar",jsonData.result.quoteID);`

script for storing the value in Env variable

2. May i know how i can use value which is stored in the CreateGLVar for the below script. how i can the quote id from first request from global variable and insert dynamically in the second request( shown below) .

[get quote id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CTKQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRa9D.png)

Answer (score 2):

Postman uses double curly braces to insert variables, which can also be used in raw request bodies.

In your specific case you can use:

`"quoteID": "{{quoteIdVariable}}"`

I am using the Postman Chrome extension Version 5.3.1, and this works for me.

*Edit: Now that the Chrome extension has been depricated, this still works with the Postman Desktop app*

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I am able to pass the variable and getting out put as success.

Comment: What if variable is a number ?

Comment: @ManojSuthar - Try removing the quotes maybe? IIRC, postman is javascript based so regular old JSON syntax should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Aaron.

I got the success when i used the "quoteID": "{{quoteIdVariable}}" in my bind API.my 2 API are working fine when i executed individually.

But I got issue when i executed API's as collection( Quote and Bind API). What i missing here if i executed as collection.

[image]
[image]

[image: Execution failed]
Failed[image]